# How to block object from changing while executing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

i have a problem when I execute a thread. The problem occurs when i delete an object from the main thread while i was executing another thread that updates that object. By the moment the second thread tries to update the object, and Exception occurs as the object no longer exists. My question is the following: How can i block other threads from modifying my object while I'm running my special thread? I want my special thread to have priority over every other thread in the application.

Thank you very much

Comment: It sounds like you want a reader-writer lock

Comment: Can you provide some code sample here.. It will be better to understand the context

Comment: Suggest you work your way through the Java concurrency tutorial:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Seems like you do not use a synchronized block.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this:

(a) Use locking or synchronized (use synchronize block on an object) way to sync the delete and object access calls

(b) EDIT: Use Atomic Integer with intial value as 1. Mark it as 0 while deleting and mark it as -1 while modifying (re-mark to 1 when done), modifying thread will check `if (atomicCounter != 0)` before proceeding to modify the object and delete thread will check `while (atomicCounter != -1)` before deleting (ie will wait to become zero)

(c) Use something like opposite to countdown latch (countup latch, it doesnt exist in Java library)

(d) Dont do anything, if exception occurs, handle it properly using catch and finally block and let the thread code continue as you wish to be

Comment: Your suggestion (b) won't work at all:  What happens if Thread A checks the counter, and finds it equal to 1 (safe to proceed).  Then thread B sets the counter to 0 and deletes the object, and then thread A proceeds to modify...?

Comment: Still doesn't work.  The problem remains:  The two concurrent threads could both check the flag, both find it equal to 1, and both proceed to interfere with one another.  Your case (b) makes the problem less likely to happen during testing, but it doesn't actually _prevent_ the problem from happening.

Comment: Since you mention `AtomicInteger`,  you might want to learn about the `AtomicInteger.compareAndSet(...)` method.  It exposes the hardware primitive (known as CMPXCHG in the x86 architecture) that underlies `synchronized` blocks and many of the algorithms in `java.util.concurrent`.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap